# Automatically print statement results in python with trace

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, trace

We are converting a series of bash scripts to Python.  In our environment, we use `set -x` to echo both lines executed and also, the results of the line to the build logs.

To take a toy example, if there is a line like `x=$(ls)` then one might see something like:

```
> ls
```

followed by the contents of the directory *without* any echo statements actually in the code.

Is there an way to get the Trace facility to do something similar?

Comment: Are you using the subprocess module to call the bash commands?

Comment: No. We are completely replacing the bash scripts with python scripts.  We are trying to *emulate* the bash output behavior in python.

Comment: I've never used it, but would the pdb module do what you're looking for? https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: I don't think so, but I will play with it and see what I get.